# How to handle precision errors in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, vyper

Say I have some division and the result is the answer is off-by-one.

I've multiplied it by 10^18 to give the decimals but the issue is its still off by one.

How do i stop repetitions of this calculation throwing it off by a considerable amount?

For example, if a user calls the function 10,000 times the answer is no longer off by one but has now deviated by 10,000.

What's the best way to handle this?

Is it ok to do this and hardcode the imprecision?

`myVariable -= foo + 1`

Comment: Please give examples of the code which is producing the off-by-one error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the context.

For many operations, like token swaps, a rounding error of `1 x 10^(-18)` is problably OK. A lot more is paid as transaction fee.

Some contracts that have accumulated error over time, like MakerDao, use more digits. In these cases I'd suggest to study carefully the effects of the rounding error over time. You would prefer a solution where the correction cancels out the error in the long term.